# Unable to convert grib2 files to geoJSON file (as polygons)

Tags: gdal, grib, grib-2

I have been working with the following GRIB2 files at https://mrms.ncep.noaa.gov/data/3DZdr/MergedZdr_02.00/. I need to setup a process to convert these to geoJSON polygons. I have tried official tools, GDAL, and broken old repos on GitHub that bring me nowhere.

My goal is to get a command working that inputs a GRIB2 and outputs a geoJSON, in a format close to (or reasonably close, plain-text, anything) to this format :

```
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [-75.9404018832492, 42.214059843606286],
          [-75.9376138443044, 42.2149380047364],
          [-75.93727048421295, 42.21432100565146],
          [-75.94007869956438, 42.21347914637607],
          [-75.9404018832492, 42.214059843606286]
        ]
      ]
     },
     "properties": {
        "value": -3.88768
     }
   }
```

This is all I need. I have tried gdal_translate, ogr2ogr and numerous tools (netCDF tools, python utilities) and I have come to the conclusion that this is not possible or I do not know what I am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I had used gdal_polygonize but it was giving whole numbers as output, and it appeared that it "wasn't working". In fact, there is a version of gdal_polygonize that will output floating point (https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/attachment/ticket/4516/gdal_polygonize.py).

Also, on Windows - not using "-q" gives a traceback error which caused even more confusion. With both of these issues resolved, it now works.

The command used was :

```
gdal_polygonize.py filename.grib2 --float -q -f "geoJSON" out.json layer fieldname
```

Comment: Hey David, I'm trying to build a map to show GFW wave forecasts from NOAA, and it's pretty hard to make progress. I can convert grib2 to geoJSON using gdal_polygonize but after importing it to maplibre nothing is shown. I'm pretty stuck, so could you point me to the right direction? I'm open to offering money for the help. Thanks so much